# FCM cordova push notification no se reciben en pagina secundaria

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, cordova

Tengo el siguiente problema con el plugin `FCM.plugin` para conectar Firebase Cloud Messaging con cordova.

Mi aplicación es un login y despues una pagina secundaria donde cargo todo el contenido. El problema esta en que no recibo notificaciones cuando me encuentro en esta segunda pagina.

Dentro del archivo `index.js` en la función onDeviceready tengo lo siguiente para obtener el token y permitir las notificaciones, hasta ahí funciona todo bien.

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
//var tokenget;

//alert(navigator.onLine ? "OnLine" : "OffLine");
if(window.localStorage.getItem("token") == null){window.localStorage.setItem("token", "")};
setTimeout(getTheToken, 1000);

function getTheToken() {
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("token") == ""){
        FCMPlugin.getToken(
            function (token) {
                if (token == null) {
                    console.log("null token");
                    setTimeout(getTheToken, 1000);
                    //window.localStorage.setItem("token", token);
                    navigator.notification.alert("Bucle");
                } else {
                    console.log("I got the token: " + token);                    
                    window.localStorage.setItem("token", token);   
                    alert("Ya tengo Token" + token);                
                }
            },
            function (err) {
                alert('error retrieving token: ' + err);
            }
        );
    }
}

FCMPlugin.onNotification(
    function(data){
        if(data.wasTapped){
//Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
            alert("Tapped: " +  JSON.stringify(data) );
        }else{
//Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
            alert("Not tapped: " + JSON.stringify(data) );
        }
    },
    function(msg){
        alert('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
        console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
    },
    function(err){
        alert('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
        console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
    }
);
//tokenget = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
```

Dentro de un archivo js aparte tengo la función con un formulario basico de login, el cual contiene:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#entrar").on("click",function(e){
        var identificador = $("#asociado_id").val();
        var token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
        //alert(token);
        login(identificador, token, "#entrar");

    });
});
```

Dentro de la función `login` hago una llamada ajax a un servicio web que me indica si el usuario se encuentra en una BD y si es correcto, lo redirige a una segunda pagina.

```
success: function(respuesta) {
                if(respuesta.tk == "true"){
                    window.localStorage.setItem("login", "true");
                   window.location.href = "main.html";
```

Cuando me encuentro en la segunda página, este no recibe notificaciones. No se a que se deba. El archivo `main.html` contiene estos script cargados.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/velocity.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main_menu.js"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
```

Nota: Incluí los archivos de `cordova.js` e `index.js` pero entra en un bucle la applicaciones y no funciona.

Comment: Puedes poner el url o nombre exacto del plugin que usas?, intento obtener push token en una app cordova con FCM pero no he tenido exito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al navegar a una página distinta, el contexto javascript se pierde.

Tienes 2 opciones:

1. Poner todo el código también en el main.html, poner el link al cordova.js, volver a registrar el deviceready, todo.
2. Buscar información sobre SPA (Single Page Apps)y convertir tu app en una de ellas, en la que sólo tienes una página que se encarga de todo. No quiere decir que sólo tenga una pantalla, si no que "navegas" a divs distintos que se muestran a pantalla completa como si fueran páginas distintas, pero que realmente siempre estás en el index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Pues parece un problema que se resuelve ordenando un poco el código.

Intenta mover la función

**FCMPlugin.onNotification(...);**

justo debajo de

**FCMPlugin.getToken(...);**

Este es el archivo **index.js** que utilizo cuando quiero que mi app tenga notificaciones push con FCM. Espero te sirva.

```
var app = {

initialize: function () {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', this.onBackKeyDown, false);
},
onDeviceReady: function () {

    app.notificacionesPush();


},

notificacionesPush: function () {

    FCMPlugin.getToken(
            function (token) {

                var obj = {"token": token};

                Ajax("http://MI-URL/webservice.php", obj, function (data) {
                    if (data.code === "OK")
                        console.info("Token de Dispositivo registrado correctamente");
                    else
                        console.info("Error en registro de Token");

                }, function () {
                    console.warn("Error en registro de Token");
                });
            },
            function (err) {
                console.warn('error retrieving token: ' + err);
            }
    );


    FCMPlugin.onNotification(
            function (data) {
                if (data.wasTapped) {
                    console.info(JSON.stringify(data));
                } else {
                    console.info(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            },
            function (msg) {
                console.info('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
            },
            function (err) {
                console.info('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
            }
    );
},
}; app.initialize();
```

Comment: Entiendo tu punto, pero el archivo index.js se ejecuta unicamente cuando la app se inicializa en el `ondeviceready` El tema es que cuando redirijo a la nueva pagina si el usuario se encontro esta segunda página no toma ningun evento de las notificaciones. No se si me de a entender @ELM